# filtering the tag set and make the sequence of bigram

Tags: python, regex

I'm sorry to ask question with same text file.
below is my working text file string.

```
The/at Fulton/np-tl County/nn-tl Grand/jj-tl Jury/nn-tl said/vbd Friday/nr an/at investigation/nn of/in Atlanta's/np$ recent/jj primary/nn election/nn produced/vbd
```

This string consists of the `"word / its tag"` format, as you can see. From this string, I want to filter only the sequence of `"noun + adjective"` and make them to the bigram. For example, `"Grand/jj-tl Jury/nn-tl"` is exact word sequence that I want. (`nn` means noun, `jj` means adjective and adjuncts such as `"-tl"` are additional information about the tag.)

Maybe this will be easy job. And I first used regex for filtering. Below is my code.

```
import re
f = open(textfile)
raw = f.read()
tag_list = re.findall("\w+/jj-?\w* \w+/nn-?\w*", raw)
print tag_list
```

This codes give me the exact words list. However, what I want is the bigram data. That code only gives me the list of words, such like this.

```
['Grand/jj-tl Jury/nn-tl', 'recent/jj primary/nn', 'Executive/jj-tl Committee/nn-tl']
```

I want this data to be converted such as below.

```
[('Grand/jj-tl, Jury/nn-tl'), ('recent/jj ,primary/nn'), ('Executive/jj-tl , Committee/nn-tl')]
```

i.e. the list of bigram data. I need your advice.

Comment: so what's the problem here? you're asking for a trivial string manipulation? (replace the space with comma-space and prepend/append ()'s)

Answer (score 1):

I think once you have found the `tag_list` it should be an easy job afterwards just using the list comprehension:

```
>>> tag_list = ['Grand/jj-tl Jury/nn-tl', 'recent/jj primary/nn', 'Executive/jj-tl Committee/nn-tl']
>>> [tag.replace(' ', ', ') for tag in tag_list]
['Grand/jj-tl, Jury/nn-tl', 'recent/jj, primary/nn', 'Executive/jj-tl, Committee/nn-tl']
```

In your original demonstration, I am not sure why do you have `('Grand/jj-tl, Jury/nn-tl')` and I am also not sure why would you like to join these bigrams using comma.

I think it would be better to have a list of list where the inner list have the bigram data:

```
>>> [tag.split() for tag in tag_list]
[['Grand/jj-tl', 'Jury/nn-tl'], ['recent/jj', 'primary/nn'], ['Executive/jj-tl', 'Committee/nn-tl']]
```